# Regular Expression for AppSettings Tags Removing commented tags

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I would like to create a regular expression which should give me the only those appsettings tags which are not commented. Following is the test string.

```
<a key="a" value="b"/><b key="b" value="b"/><!--<c key="c" value="c"/>-->
<d key="d" value="d"/>
```

I've come up with following regular expression so far.

```
(?<!<!--)<[^>]*/+>
```

Her i'm testing the negative lookahead of

```
<!--
```

but it's not working. Any idea.

Comment: What do you want to do, match all the comments and replace with nothing, or match everything else

Comment: @TheGeneral match everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another good opportunity to apply the trash can approach: everything we want goes into the 1st capturing group, the rest goes into the overall match and will be completely disregarded.

A regex that achieves just that could look like this:

```
<!--.*?-->|(<\s*\w+[^>]*>)
```

Explanation:

- `<!--.*?-->` the first alternation matches HTML comment blocks and everything between lazy
- `(<\s*\w+[^>]*>)` the second matches any simple XHTML tag

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xRF1Ow/1)

So, only if there is a value in `$1` we take note of it.

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/6LXkuq):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<!--.*?-->|(<\s*\w+[^>]*>)";
        string input = @"<a key=""a"" value=""b""/><b key=""b"" value=""b""/><!--<c key=""c"" value=""c""/>-->
<d key=""d"" value=""d""/>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            if(m.Groups[1].Success)
                Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Another pattern that could achieve a similar thing is to make use of negative lookarounds to assert the comment tags:

```
(?<!<!--)(<\s*\w+[^>]*>)(?!-->)
```

[**Demo 2**](https://regex101.com/r/7wKue6/1/)

Comment: Your solution is also matching the tag in comment tag as well, which shouldn't be selected.

Comment: @Zeb-ur-Rehman The tags in HTML comments are matched but disregarded. This is the idea here. Have you clicked on the sample code link?